# Arrays.toString - How to choose individual elements

Tags: android-studio

This return me all elements in the array.How to choose only first element?

```
private String[] androidosnames;
...
...
Toast.makeText(getContext(),Arrays.toString(androidosnames), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to access the first element of your array:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),androidosnames[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, I recommend you to learn the basics of Arrays in Java.